# How to display fullcalendar smoothly?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a PHP MVC application (based on Laravel).  I am loading fullcalendar via a script in the bottom of the page, as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
            firstDay: 1,
            footer: {
                right: 'month basicWeek listDay'
            }
        });
    });
```

The obvious problem is that, when I navigate to the page, the layout is rendered, but the calendar is not.  After a few moments, the calendar is rendered too.  This is not the smooth user experience I am aiming for.

What's the best way of dealing with this?

As far as I can see, I:

- Could render the calendar on the server side, but this would require a server-side JS environment, such as node.js
- I could hide the entire contents of the page, until the calendar has rendered.  This might improve the experience, but is still not great

What other options are there?

Comment: Sounds like you must have a lot of stuff on that page. It typically renders very quickly

Comment: You can put a placeholder only where the calendar will appear, like a div with some loading gif or text, then use the [eventAfterAllRender() callback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) to remove the div and show fullcalendar

Comment: How do you load your events on calendar? You might want to show only that view events e.g. 1 week or so using ajax.